# How to run a pl script of apache tuner on debian?

Tags: apache, debian

What I need to do to run this script to tune the apache on debian x64?

https://github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachebuddy.pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. It's easy.

root@localhost:~# perl apachebuddy.pl